# Deny him and measure out

Tags: meaning

I can't understand the meaning of this sentence - 
"But she knew it was unfair of her, given that she barely saw her father, given that she continued to measure out her contact with him, whether to deny herself or to deny him, she could not be sure."

1. What is the meaning of "measure out"? I guess it means to measure. But again I am not sure what it means "to measure out her contact with him"
2. What does it mean "to deny herself or to deny him"? It does not sound complete. Deny him what?

Comment: Here "measure out" means to "mete out", i.e., to give out in small portions. In other words, she is not seeing him very much. Why? She's either denying herself contact with him, or denying him contact with herself. And she's unsure which.

Comment: I'll add my comment as an answer to avoid leaving this as an unanswered question.

Answer (score 1):

Here "measure out" means to "mete out", i.e., to give out in small portions. In other words, she is not seeing him very much. Why? She's either denying herself contact with him, or denying him contact with herself. And she's unsure which.